# SAP Subreport will print to PDF but not to viewer or printer

Tags: crystal-reports, reportviewer

I have two different SAP Crystal Reports, one has sub reports and the other doesn't.  For whatever reason the simple CR prints to the printer, to PDF and to the viewer just fine.  The CR with subreports only prints to PDF for whatever reason.  This is leading me to believe there's nothing inherently wrong with the report itself otherwise it wouldn't work when I save to PDF.

A snippet of my code is below (in VB):

```
            Select Case PrintMedia
            Case PrintType.Printer
                crOrderPrintout.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
            Case PrintType.Viewer
                Dim frmReportViewer As New frmReportViewer
                frmReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crOrderPrintout
                frmReportViewer.ShowDialog()
            Case PrintType.File
                crOrderPrintout.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, String.Format("C:\Documents and Settings\{0}\Desktop\{1}.pdf", mdlSharedVars.StripDomainFromFullUsername(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name), ReceiptID))
            Case Else
                crOrderPrintout.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
        End Select
```

For clarification the PrintMedia is a variable whose type is a custom enum of mine, PrintType.

When I try to show the report with the subreport in the viewer or print to printer I get a "Index was out of range.  Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter: index." error.  Yet the simple, non-subreport CR works just fine regardless of the PrintMedia.

Don't suppose anyone has any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with this for longer than I care to imagine, it turns out there was a problem with one of the fields in the crystal report display string.  Basically I started the report from scratch, adding in piece by piece trying to isolate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the report in an off the shelf Crystal viewer or Crystal Reports itself? Does it work?

Maybe try setting the printer options in page setup to "No Printer (Optimize for screen display)"